# How to set current date time in Configuration Block

Tags: spotfire

i follow the instruction(below link) to set trigger to the current date time in Configuration Block
but the **trigger={date}{time};** does not work, it return error
" the configuration block was not well-formed."
who know the right expression for the current date? thanks a lot
https://support.tibco.com/s/article/How-to-append-rows-and-update-data-table-on-a-frequent-basis

Answer (score 0):

this looks like either a typo on the article, or a bug in the Automation Services Job Builder. you can get around this message by surrounding the values with quotes, so

`trigger="{date}{time}";`

while the quotes are not required (according to [Configuration Block documentation](https://community.tibco.com/wiki/create-configuration-block-tibco-spotfire)), I would argue that it's a best practice because you never know if the value you're passing is going to jank up the configuration block parser.

also a tip: you can and probably should test any configuration blocks in the Web Player before deploying a job in Automation Services. when doing this, don't forget to URLEncode, like, everything. here's an example from the documentation I linked above:

`http://spotfire.cloud.tibco.com/spotfire/wp/OpenAnalysis?file=/Gallery/Introduction%20to%20Spotfire&configurationBlock=SetFilter(
tableName=%22World%20Bank%20Data%22,columnName=%22Region%22,values=%7B%22North%20America%22,%22Europe%20%26%20Central%20Asia%22%7D);`

and [a link of that example in action](http://spotfire.cloud.tibco.com/spotfire/wp/OpenAnalysis?file=/Gallery/Introduction%20to%20Spotfire&configurationBlock=SetFilter(%20tableName=%22World%20Bank%20Data%22,columnName=%22Region%22,values=%7B%22North%20America%22,%22Europe%20%26%20Central%20Asia%22%7D);).

Comment: also thanks for pointing this out. I'll open up a ticket with support to get the documentation you found fixed and/or any potential bug in the job builder solved.

Comment: I got this response from TIBCO Support: Currently, there seems to be defect with {time} field, it does not show minutes and seconds if document property data type is datetime. If document property datatype is changed to string, it updates complete current datetime value. FYI :)